# Is it possible using protractor to find out the element at certain coordinates?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have an SVG rect that acts as a container for other SVG rects. I would like to click on the container but there is a chance that in the middle of the container there is an inner rect, in which case I would click on the inner rect.

Is there any way, in protractor, I can find out if there is an element at certain coordinates and get that element? Having that info I can search for an area of the container that doesn't have any inner rect.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing: using "element(by.js('')) and using "document.elementFromPoint(x, y)" you can get an element from a set of coordinates.

```
let el = element(by.js("return document.elementFromPoint(350, 90)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is an wrapper on selenium which gives some more functionality which are handle angular website with selenium.

That means selenium existing functionality still in it.

Yes we can find co-ordinate in selenium.

Example Java code:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        Point point = element.getLocation();
        System.out.println("Element's Position from left side is: "+point.getX()+" pixels.");
        System.out.println("Element's Position from top is: "+point.getY()+" pixels.");
```

You just need to change this code in javascript or typescript for protractor

Comment: That is not what I meant. Having a set of coordinates I would like to find out if there is any element at those coordinates. And if there is I would like to get that element

Comment: Nicolae you can not find element using coordinations.. while its a wrong practice as if your resolutions change the script will fail